# HResult 0x80040204 from IMediaObject::ProcessInput

Tags: c++, pcm, hresult, resampling, dmo

I get this Hresult when i resample PCM Sound to a IEEE:Float Sound with DirectXMediaResampler.
Changing the bits per sample with the same sampling rate is no problem. Also resamppling from IEEE:Float to PCM.
This HResult is not documented in context with a DMO object.
And it doesn't happen on every resampling but periodically.

Does anyone know or could guess what it means.

Answer (score 0):

That's DMO_E_NOTACCEPTING; [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd406959.aspx) says:

> DMO_E_NOTACCEPTING: Data cannot be accepted.

You can see the code that generates this in dmoimpl.h, although without the derived DMO code I don't think that helps (it means the DMO's `InternalAcceptingInput` method didn't return `S_OK`).

I guess this all means that the ResamplerDMO doesn't like your input data. Is it definitely set up correctly?

Comment: Because I resample very little packages of sound (~18ms) and this happens every few seconds (but it depends on the difference of the in- and output sample rate how often it happens, just now I resample from 441000 to 32000 and it happens every 4 seconds) this is so strange to me. I have no idea why the DMO only don't like my input every few seconds. And it also happens if every sample contains the same data.

Comment: It seems to happen when the last call to ProcessOutput set the "incomplete" flag on the output buffer, indicating that you must call ProcessOutput again prior to proceeding with ProcessInput.